# React Redux with Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am fetching data from firebase and and printing on screen through a map function but i am not to get data.
please tell me what mistake i am doing.
below are the images of my code

Reducer

```
   case actionTypes.GETFEEDBACK:
    return Object.assign({}, states, {
        getFeedbacksData:  action.payload
        });        
        default:
        return states;
}
```

Action

```
export function getFeedbacksData(){
console.log('helloo');
return (dispatch) => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(()=>{
        if(firebase.auth().currentUser){
        var Rootref=firebase.database().ref().child("user/"+firebase.auth().currentUser.uid+'/feedbacks/');
        Rootref.on("value",snap=>{
            dispatch({
                    type:actionTypes.GETFEEDBACK, payload:snap.val()
          });
        })

            }
          })
```

Maping

```
           {
         //   Object.keys(this.props.getfeedback).length > 0 ?

              this.props.getfeedback !== null ?

            this.props.getfeedback.map((item,index) => (
                <TableRow  key={index}>
                      <TableCell style={{ maxWidth: "500px", width: "500px" }} >
                        {item.feedback}
                      </TableCell >
                      <TableCell >{this.props.currentUserName}</TableCell >
                      <TableCell >{this.props.currentUserEmail}</TableCell >
                      <TableCell ><Button color="secondary" onClick={this.deletefeedback.bind(this,item.count)} >Delete</Button></TableCell >  
                </TableRow>
```

)
)
  : 
''
}

mapStateToprops

```
   function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return({
      getfeedback:state.rootReducer.getFeedbacksData,
      currentUserName: state.rootReducer.currentUser.name,
      currentUserEmail: state.rootReducer.currentUser.email,
    }
  )
}
```

[Action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNwT0.png)

[Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpV4X.png)

[MapStateToReducer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKiPC.png)

[Reducer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqkXM.png)

Comment: Please paste your code here as text not as image.

Comment: see now, is it better for your readability??

Comment: Are you sure you dispatches `getFeedbacksData` action? if so, check console log, do you see any errors? Install redux devtools extension and check that `actionTypes.GETFEEDBACK` fires.

Comment: yes, i am sure i dispatch getFeedbacksData action, but console is showing noting and that is the main problem, and i am not able to solve it i am very new to this world